# computational cost power matrix $A^k$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Can you help me?

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which it is the computational cost
$A^{k}=A\cdot A\cdot\ldots\cdot A$?

Comment: $O(\log(k)n^{2.3728639})$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20873/whats-the-fastest-way-to-take-powers-of-a-square-matrix

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra

Answer (score 1):

$$O(\log(k)\times n^{2.3728639})$$

The $\log(k)$ comes from the fact that you can recursively compute $A^{2n+1}$ as $(A^n)^2\times A$ and $A^{2n}$ as $(A^n)^2$.

The $n^{2.3728639}$ comes from matrix multiplication using the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) which is the current-record-holding algorithm.

Comment: But the algorithm is $\begin{array}{c}
A\cdot A=A^{2}\\
A^{2}\cdot A=A^{3}\\
A^{3}\cdot A=A^{4}\\
\vdots\\
A^{k-1}\cdot A=A^{k}
\end{array}$

Comment: Then change the $\log(k)$ to $k$. Nobody told you to use such a naive algorithm.